# passing JavaScript object to PHP not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, object

I'm trying to send my javascript object to PHP via `JSON.stringify()`

Javascript:

```
$('#save').on('click touch', function(){
    obj = {
        "1" : {
            "1" : "hey",
            "2" : "hay"
            },              
        "2" : {
            "1" : "hey",
            "2" : "hay"
            }
    }

    var json = JSON.stringify( obj );
    console.log(json)
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("p").text(data);
        }
    });
});
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php 
    $obj = json_decode($json);
    echo $obj;
?>
```

But this code returns an error saying that `$json` is not defined. 
I have no idea why this is not working.

Comment: You have not set the `data` attribute on `$.ajax` options.

Comment: POST data will be available in the `$_POST` variable in PHP

Comment: @csum: only if OP actually bothers to tell jquery to **USE** that `json` var in the ajax call...

Comment: @MarcB yup, true. It was more of a general statement. POST data is in `$_POST`

Comment: I have fixed the issue. Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. You are not sending any data with the request
2. That's not the way you'll get the value from a request in PHP

First, add this*:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data : { json: json }, // <---------------------
    ...
```

<sub><sup>* this works just because jQuery implementation will automatically convert any non-string data argument into a form-urlencoded query string. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).</sup></sub>

Then, in your PHP, you should do:

```
$jsonStr = $_POST['json'];
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
```

---

### Edit:

Another possible way:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data : json , // <---------------------
    ...
```

This way, your data will not be a valid `form-urlencoded` input, so PHP will not parse it into `$_POST`, but you still can get the contents of your input doing this:

```
$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_decode($jsonStr);
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind the 2nd option not being a valid `form-urlencoded` input? Is it due to the contents of the `json` variable? The keys being numeric?

Comment: `form-urlencoded` values are in the form `param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3`...

Comment: Basically, it's a query string.

Comment: So then wrapping your var in `{json: ___ }` solves this?

Comment: Solves because `jQuery` will automatically convert any object into a `form-urlencoded` string. Might not work in other Ajax libs.

Comment: See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): _"Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string"_

Comment: I fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos I see, I forgot `json` var was a string via `JSON.stringify( obj );` and not an object.

Answer (score 2):

Well - you never pass your data in the AJAX request!

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: json //<---- RIGHT HERE
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("p").text(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats half the problem

Comment: In addition, OP should assing `$json = $_POST['json']` unless OP has `register_globals=On`

Comment: don't forget the comma after `json`

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos: uh, php has no idea what json is. a json string is just a plain text string to php. php expects `key=value` pairs in POST, `value` by itself is utterly meaningless. register_globals never did, and never will,decode json...

Comment: I meant this part: `$obj = json_decode($json)`. If `register_globals=On` and the data is passed under the 'json' key, like `json={"foo":"bar"}`, it would work.

Comment: In this example, data would not be parsed into `$_POST` since it isn't valid `form-urlencoded` data. The contents could be gotten using `$jsonStr = file_get_contents("php://input")` though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the obj with the ajax request

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data : json,
    dataType : 'json' // for json response
    ...
```

Comment: `dataType` refers to the expected response, no the request.

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos in the comment is says 'for json response'

Answer (score 0):

Check here for reference [jQuery ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp)

*Data parameter*: Specifies data to be sent to the server.

Try this:

```
$('#save').on('click touch', function(){
        obj = {
       "1" : {
           "1" : "hey",
           "2" : "hay"
        },              
    "2" : {
        "1" : "hey",
        "2" : "hay"
        }
}

var json = JSON.stringify( obj );

$.ajax({
    data : json,
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("p").text(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: `dataType` refers to the expected response, no the request.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your ajax code with this.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: json
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        $("p").text(data);
    }
});
```

For ajax php

```
<?php 
    $obj = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    echo $obj;
?>
```